# Recursive template classes

Tags: c++11, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I have two classes that need to keep references of each other as follow:

```
template <typename S>
class H { 
public:
  H(const S& s): s_{s} {}
private:
  const S& s_;
}
```

And then

```
template <typename H>
class S { 
public:
  S(const H& h): h_{h} {}
private:
  const H& h_;
}
```

There is no way I can define anything like

```
Service<ItsHandler<Service<....>
```

Any better idea?

Comment: Why do you need templates here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about Abstract base classes and polymorphism?:

```
class baseHandler {
public:
    virtual func1() = 0;
    virtual ~baseHandler() = 0;
};

template <typename S>
class H : public baseHandler {
public:
  H(const S& s): s_{s} {}
private:
  const S& s_;
};

//template <typename H>
class S {
public:
  S(const baseHandler& h): h_{h} {}
private:
  const baseHandler& h_;
};
```

Comment: This is an instance of one of [Scott Meyers's "most important C++ 'Aha!' moments"](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/top_cpp_aha_moments.html), specifically the one related to Boost shared_ptr's custom deleter.

Comment: @metal: interesting article series, thanks for the link

Comment: @ted: Will do something similar, appreciated. Cheers.